# How to do a loop time stamp function for a file created with fopen in C?

Tags: c

I would like to insert the date in 3 different file names with a time stamp function doing a loop. I already have a working time stamp function but how I do it to loop? I tried passing an argument to the function but is not working.

Thats what i have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char* time_stamp(int i)
{
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
static char buffer [80];
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
char file_name[3][50] = {"name1.txt", "name2.txt", "name3.txt"};
strftime (buffer,80,file_name[i],timeinfo);

return buffer;
}

int main ()
{

int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
 {

  const char * (*filename_ptr)();
  filename_ptr = &time_stamp();


  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen(filename_ptr(), "w+");
  if( !fp )
     return 1;
  fprintf(fp, "%s", output.buffer);
  fclose( fp );

  if( output.buffer )
  {
    free ( output.buffer );
    output.buffer = 0;
    output.size = 0;
  }
 }

}
```

Whitout the "int i" argument it works fine but only prints one name. How can I do the loop work?

Comment: I tried your time stamp function (basically using `printf("Timestamp: '%s'\n", time_stamp(i));`). Looks like calling `time_stamp(1)` results in "name1.txt" and so on. I guess that is not the intended result. How did you test that function before trying to let it loose on your file system?

Comment: Otherwise I got your code working quite fine by only listening to `gcc -Wall`. By the way, please try to compile the code you post here - not the one you kept and which defines `output` without telling us.

Comment: Thx Yunnosch, yes I did and with printf works fine, but with fopen I have to pass a pointer as first argument that's why filename_ptr = &time_stamp(); and doesn't compile. Wherever I use the "i" in &time_stamp(i) or filename_ptr(i) it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
filename_ptr = &time_stamp();
```

you ***call*** the `time_stamp` function with no argument, and take a pointer to the returned string.

If you want a pointer to the function (why?) then drop the parentheses.

Later you use the pointer to the function (which doesn't point to a function) and call it, *again* without an argument.

All of this should cause the compiler to should loudly at you, and lead to plenty of *undefined behavior*.

Furthermore there is no `output` variable, which will lead to a compiler *error*.

By the way, the `time_stamp` function doesn't really do anything with the time. It basically only copies a fixed static string into the buffer.

---

To call the function in a loop, just do it? Passing the loop iterator variable as argument.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(time_stamp(i));
    ...
}
```

Comment: It worked using time_stamp(i) as first argument but this let me even more confused. It is fopen not expecting a pointer "const char *" as first argument? That is why i used the `filename_ptr = &time_stamp()`; in the first place because otherwise wasn't working. What pice of knowledge am I lacking here?

Comment: @Jesus But you declared the `time_stamp` function to *return* a `const char *`. If you use the address-of operator then you get something of type `const char **` which is not correct.